# recover files between hook, tpl and front controller

Tags: php, prestashop, smarty

I create a hook allowing the user to send a csv file.
I want to get the data (the file) that the user sends via a form (present in views/templates/hook), to get it in controller/front/files.php, and insert it in my database, anyone have an idea?

my hook in mymodule.php

```
public function hookDisplayLeftColumnProduct($params)
{
    $this->context->smarty->assign([
        'files' => Tools::getValue('files')
    ]);

    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'mymodule.tpl');
}
```

views/templates/hook/mymodule.tpl

```
<div id="mymodule_block_home">
    <form method="POST">
        <label for="files">Envoyer un fichier CSV</label>
        <input type="file" name="files" id="files">
        <button>Envoyer</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

my front controller who's not good I guess

```
class MyModuleFilesFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{
    public function initContent()
    {
        parent::initContent();
        $files = Tools::getValue('files');

        $this->setTemplate('module:mymodule/views/templates/front/files.tpl');
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

It is not a PrestaShop-specific problem. You might want to read about uploading files in PHP there:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_file_uploading.htm

A few hints:

- check if there is something to upload, always
- make sure to validate user input, always

One more thing. I see that you hook your module into the product page. You could have the logic of uploading a file directly in your hook. You don't need an extra controller for that.

You could do something like:

```
public function hookDisplayLeftColumnProduct($params)
{
    if (Tools::isSubmit('yourSubmitButtonName') {
        // here's the logic of uploading the file
    }

    // the rest of the code
}
```